# Div using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, listbox

Here I am working on a listbox and i am iterating all elements of this listbox. Here 'list2' is Id of listbox and elements of this taken from 'list2' :

```
 $(function(){
    $("#button1").click(function(){

        $("#list1 > option:selected").each(function(){
            $(this).remove().appendTo("#list2");

        });
    });

    $("#button2").click(function(){
        $("#list2 > option:selected").each(function(){
            $(this).remove().appendTo("#list1");

        });
    });
});
```

Here I made a button3 to show all elements of 'list2'. Click on this it will show using div 'placeholder;

```
  $("#button3").click(function(){
         var count = $("#list2 option").length;


          $("#list2 > option").each(function() {


         document.getElementById("error").style.display='none';
           document.getElementById("placeholder").style.display='block';
           document.getElementById("placeholder").innerHTML= document.getElementById("placeholder").innerHTML+'<p>'+this.text+'</p>';
});
```

Here if click on 'button3' then i am getting expected result but if again click on button3 then it will show again the same result but at different location. Number of times I click on this button it will show number of display/result but at different-different location.

I want this result only for a single time.

**Ques:** Is there any way to achieve this.If someone click on button3 and the elements are the same then it won't print any more but if someone change the elements of list2 and then it will show the changed result.

Thanks

Comment: please create a fiddle.

Comment: Also why are you using doucment.getElementById when you have jQuery available ?

Comment: Instead of document.getElementById how can we achieve this?? plz refer me link u have any.. I am a beginner.

Comment: You do it by the same way youre selecting button3
`$("#error").hide();` would be the substitute for the error line